# How to store only the peaks of an FFT with GNU Radio Companion?

Tags: gnuradio-companion

I am attempting to capture the 2.4-2.5GHz spectrum into a binary file for post-processing in MATLAB. I have a .grc file to collect the spectrum, but I would like to collect only the peak values for each frequency. I know there is a peak detector block in GNU Radio companion but I don't believe this is what I need. I will attach a picture of the current [WiFi Spectrum Flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1QSM.png).
I am not very experienced with GNU Radio Companion, the reason I'm using it right now is because this project was passed along and it was the choice of the previous team. Any help with this would be appreciated.